# Wordpress rewrite url to plugin file

Tags: redirect, url-rewriting, wordpress

I am not able to redirect to plugin page ..

I get page not found..

```
add_action( 'init', 'myplugin_rewrite_internal' );
function myplugin_rewrite_internal() {
     global $wp_rewrite;

    add_rewrite_rule('oauth/facebook/$', plugins_url('/oauth/facebook/index.php' 
    ,dirname(__FILE__)), 'top');
    $wp_rewrite->flush_rules(true);  // This should really be done in a plugin activation
}
```

URL i am calling

www.example.com/oauth/facebook/index.php

I tired mod_rewite_url still  I get page not found

```
 add_action('generate_rewrite_rules', array(&$this, 'generate_rewrite_rules'));
 add_filter('mod_rewrite_rules', array(&$this, 'mod_rewrite_rules'));

function generate_rewrite_rules() {
    global $wp_rewrite;
    $non_wp_rules = array(
        'oauth/facebook/?$plugin_name' => plugins_url('/oauth/facebook/index.php' 
    ,dirname(__FILE__)),

    );

    $wp_rewrite->non_wp_rules = $non_wp_rules + $wp_rewrite->non_wp_rules;
}

function mod_rewrite_rules($rules) {
    $rules = preg_replace('/^(RewriteRule ^.*+/?$)plugin_name (/)(.*) ([QSA,L])$/im', '1 3 [R=301,L]', $rules);
    return $rules;
}
```

Please correct me..
I have tried this many times..
add_rewrite_url works only with registered taxonomy,tags,post_types names like category,custom post_type
What if I want to redirect to page that is not register taxonomy,tags,post_types?

Answer (score 0):

As the tag I was using not any of the type (e.g. posts, pages, category, author, search)..
and also pretty urls may not be enabled on the wordpress . I  cannot use add_rewrite_rule();

if I need to use add_rewrite_rule() then pretty urls must be enabled.

So only way to rewrite the url is by editing the htaccess file. so this is the function

which needs to be called to save the rules to htaccess on plugin activation

```
function mod_rewrite_rules($rules) {

$home_root = parse_url(home_url());
if ( isset( $home_root['path'] ) )
    $home_root = trailingslashit($home_root['path']);
else
    $home_root = '/';

$rules = array();
$rules[] =  "<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>";
$rules[] =  "   RewriteEngine On";
$rules[] =  "   RewriteBase $home_root";    
    $rules[] =   "  RewriteRule ^oauth/facebook/?$  wp-content/plugins/my_plugin/file.php? [L]\n"; // Prevent -f checks on index.php.
$rules[] = "</IfModule>\n"; 
$home_path = get_home_path();
$htaccess_file = $home_path.'.htaccess';

// If the file doesn't already exist check for write access to the directory and whether we have some rules.
// else check for write access to the file.

if (file_exists($htaccess_file) && is_writable($home_path) &&  is_writable($htaccess_file)) {
        insert_with_markers( $htaccess_file, 'Coupon', $rules );        
}   
    }
}
}
```